# permissions cross host and docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Im setting a dev environment using docker & wsl 2

no much experience in the topic , just basic knowledge of linux terminal commands and the concept of docker .

now Im trying to dockerize a laravel application in an nginx container , the nginx ships with a user called 'www-data' , but my host has the user of 'ahmed' .

now , when I mount the application directory to the container , I get permission issues regarding to the truth saying that the user inside the container has no rights to access the files maintained by the user 'ahmed'

changing the ownership to www-data didnt work with me , the vscode server ( running remotely from wsl ) cant update files because the permissions were set to another user 'www-data' !

so what to do in this case ?

Comment: This is the exact same issue I'm having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65925625/how-do-i-set-up-file-ownership-between-wsl-vs-code-and-a-docker-container

Did you manage to fix this?