# How do I set-up file ownership between WSL + VS Code and a Docker container?

Tags: wordpress, docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My issue is that I don't know (nor understand) how to best configure file ownership between a host and a container. I'm a front-end dev by trade so out of my depth here.

Host: Windows 10 running WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). Using the VS Code WSL Remote extension.

Container: `php:7.4-fpm` running WordPress.

WordPress is running just fine but when I want to install a plugin via the CMS or upload a file to the Media library I'm met with "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2021/01.".

I think this is because the container has `1000:1000` set as file owner/group but the host machine lists the same files as `andrew:andrew`. If I change the container to `www-data:www-data` then WordPress uploads work but I then cannot use VS Code to edit files - the host files also change to `www-data:www-data` (not a valid user on the host) - I'm met with the following from VS Code:

"Failed to save 'front-page.php': Unable to write file 'vscode-remote://wsl+ubuntu-20.04/home/andrew/my-app/app/wp-content/themes/my-theme/theme/front-page.php' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/andrew/my-app/app/wp-content/themes/my-theme/theme/front-page.php')"

For what it's worth I believe my directory permissions are set-up correctly all the way down to `/uploads` with `drwxr-xr-x`.

Is there a specific way I need to configure file ownership to ensure I can both use WordPress uploads feature and also make file amends in VS Code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. [Found a solution here that worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64270988/2573629). This 'locks' the user that owns the files in the container to `www-data` whilst preserving the original user, `andrew` on the host.